# How to get this desired output

Tags: bash-scripting

I have this file:

```
Alias name: ciscobas
Owner: CN=DI0DGQB2QG9RK8OHMJ5C, O=Duo Security
Issuer: CN=DI0DGQB2QG9RK8OHMJ5C, O=Duo Security
Valid from: Thu Jun 15 15:08:49 AST 2023 until: Tue Jan 19 06:14:07 AST 2038
Alias name: mobca
Owner: CN=Mobily Root CA, OU=Security And Privacy, O=Etihad Etisalat Company - Mobily, L=RIYADH, ST=RIYADH, C=SA
Issuer: CN=Mobily Root CA, OU=Security And Privacy, O=Etihad Etisalat Company - Mobily, L=RIYADH, ST=RIYADH, C=SA
Valid from: Sat Apr 17 08:13:51 AST 2021 until: Thu Apr 17 08:13:51 AST 2036

Alias name: mobsubca
Owner: CN=Mobily IT CA, OU=Security And Privacy, O=Etihad Etisalat Company - Mobily, L=RIYADH, ST=RIYADH, C=SA
Issuer: CN=Mobily Root CA, OU=Security And Privacy, O=Etihad Etisalat Company - Mobily, L=RIYADH, ST=RIYADH, C=SA
Valid from: Fri Apr 23 06:50:32 AST 2021 until: Wed Apr 23 06:50:32 AST 2031
   accessMethod: caIssuers
```

And i want it to look like this.

```
Alias name: ciscobas
until:  Tue Jan 19 06:14:07 AST 2038
Alias name: mobca 
until: Thu Apr 17 08:13:51 AST 2036
```

After doing this, i will need to check when that date will expire within next 30 days.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please can you check that this post is correct - I've modified the formatting (just changed your copy-pastes to code blocks) - which seems to make more sense if I am understanding what you are looking to do.

Comment: Also, we are not a script writing service - you should show us what you have tried and where you are failing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a partial solution to your question - ie it converts the input to the output -

```
  egrep "^Alias name: | (.*)until:(.*)" file.name  | sed 's/Valid from:\(.*\)until:\(.*\)/\2/'
```

It is unclear from your post if you only wanted the first 2 answers, or if your post was truncated.    I've not attacked the much more interesting problem of checking if the date expires in the next 30 days.  This is a whole different question and is inconsistent with the one you asked.  (You will need to parse the output and then match the date.   I am sure it can be done with bash - but I don't know that its the correct tool for the job.    If you are dead set on this, can we make assumptions about the filesystem - ie that the filesystem can support timestamps?